Verilog-A compiler directive inside an analog block - legal or not?
In Verilog-A, we desire to insert an  `include directive inside a module and specifically inside an analog process block.  Is this legal or not?
I can not find any prohibition in the Accelera LRM, but I also can't find any examples using this construct in any textbook or online guide.
Specific trivial example of desired code, below.
The included file is where it is, because it will operate on the analog variable values preceding it.
module mymodule(n1,n2);
    // parameter declarations, etc.
    analog begin
        // bunch of code, eg

        I <+ V(n1,n2)/R

        `include foo.va  
        // foo will contain executable code

    end
endmodule 
               


Verilog-A is an analog only subset of Verilog-AMS, and Verilog-AMS inherits all of the compiler directives from Verilog IEEE 1364; you would not see any examples of it in the LRM.
Compiler directives like  `include and  `define are interpreted as a text pre-processor, meaning that they don't have any understanding of syntax until after processing the text.
Of course, any tool is free to choose what parts of the LRM to implement, so you should try small examples to make sure they are supported.
